# How to view all event handlers in DOM using Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to view a list of event handlers in the DOM using Chrome developer tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Elements tab, the right-hand part has options `Styles`, `Computed`, `Event Listeners`, `DOM Breakpoints`, and `Properties`. Select `Event Listneners`.